# Google App Engine Launcher not working

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I've installed the Google App Engine SDK for PHP:

1. Download and install Python 2.7
2. Download and install Google App Engine SDK 1.8.8

After those steps, I got an GAE launcher on my desktop. I clicked on it, it displayed a loading icon, and a few seconds later the icon changed back and nothing happened. The launcher seems not to work.

I'm using Windows 8.1 and have installed XAMPP before (hope this is not the problem).

Comment: No one answer? However, the main purpose is create and deloy my work on app. Google has other option called "Push-to-Deloy", it allow me to create a repo on code.google.com and automaticly deloy to appengine whenever I push something. Thank you all.

Comment: git is better to use than the launcher anyway... tho there is also option of deploying using "appcfg.py update" but you won't need it now.

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/?hl=en_US  dowloand Google Cloud SDK install it then 
launch Google App Engine launcher --> Edit-->Preferences-->Python path--> new python should be installed probably under the drive C: then select Python27x86 -->pythonw.exe.

Comment: How about _python.exe_? Is there any difference?